# jmeter test plan navigation pane font size

Tags: java, swing, jmeter

I was able to change the font size for `jMeter` by adjusting `UIDefaults`, as shown in this SO answer to [Change Swing font size from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12424399/5363878).

However, the navigation pane on the left for test plans still has extremely small font. Is there any way to change this?

[image: Image of the navigation pane.]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

Open jmeter\src\core\org\apache\jmeter\gui\MainFrame.java and find this method:

```
private TreeCellRenderer getCellRenderer() {
    DefaultTreeCellRenderer rend = new JMeterCellRenderer();
    rend.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    return rend;
}
```

Change the value of font size from 11 to what you prefer and rebuild project using Ant.

[That's how Jmeter looks after changing this value to 24.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6lta.jpg)

Comment: How to rebuild with Ant. This folder doesn't have `build.xml`

Comment: can you explain more about ant re-build?

Comment: You can download jmeter project from here: https://github.com/apache/jmeter. There is some info about using ant in readme. Basically, you'll need to just run 'ant' in console in order to rebuild jmeter.

Comment: github sources has different signature: `private TreeCellRenderer getCellRenderer() {
        DefaultTreeCellRenderer rend = new JMeterCellRenderer();
        return rend;
    }`

Comment: Ok, seems it has been changed since I answered to this question (11/27/15). You can try to manually add rend.setFont... method, I suppose it should work too.

Comment: Also I've heard that jmeter 3.0 will have some new features for hdpi monitors or smth that should obsolete that hardcoded rend.setFont method. I think the github trunk already contains these modifications. Can't check it now though.