# How to change font size for JMeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

I am using JMeter with 2.13 version.
I want to increase font size for JMeter.

I have tried following question [jmeter test plan navigation pane font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719824/jmeter-test-plan-navigation-pane-font-size). However for 2.13 version doesn't have `src` folder.

Here is a picture, how it looks now:

[image]

***How to change font size for JMeter `test plan` section.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In order to get `src` folder you need to download JMeter source code separately, i.e. from [here](http://www-us.apache.org/dist//jmeter/source/apache-jmeter-2.13_src.zip). Unpack the folder and make [required changes](https://bitbucket.org/glinius/jmeter-font-increase/commits/8c735769338c1b6919687fc60e5d5762d872cc93)
2. You will need [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) to build JMeter. Install it and make sure that %ANT_HOME%/bin folder is added to your system PATH variable
3. Build JMeter using next 2 commands:

   - `ant download_jars`
   - `ant package`
4. Now your should be able to run JMeter with increased font from apache-jmeter-2.13/bin folder like:

   ```
   jmeter -Djmeter.dialog.font=20 .....
   ```

   or ir you want to make font size change permanent add the next line to *system.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   jmeter.dialog.font=20
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up. See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information regarding JMeter properties usage.

---

If you trust me and Bitbucket hosting you can take the risk and get compiled binary with aforementioned change from

https://bitbucket.org/glinius/jmeter-font-increase/downloads/ApacheJMeter_core.jar

and dropping it to /lib/ext folder of your JMeter installation, however downloading binaries of unknown origin is not recommended (your PC can become a member of a botnet or someone's bitcoin mining farm) so it's better to take above 4 steps.

Comment: How to change font size for `JMeter 3`? Can you help with this one?

Comment: `required changes` link asks for login to Atlassian. is it supposed to be that way?

Comment: nope, the repo became private for some reason, it should be publicly available now again

Answer (score 12):

Since JMeter 3.2, use Menu:

> Options > Zoom In
>
> Options > Zoom Out

See this:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59995

***JMeter 3.0*** (released 2 weeks ago) has improved regarding the icons and tables but does not yet support full HiDPI mode:

See this particular bug:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58426
- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59168

To set properties, see:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#hidpi

Now for fonts, you can use ***Swing mechanism***. To do that, add to `jmeter.sh` or `jmeter.bat` the JVM System property:

> -Dswing.plaf.metal.controlFont=Dialog-20

And ensure you use the ***Cross Platform LAF***

Comment: The `JMeter 3` version has the same font as previous. How can I change it?

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer, if ok you should upvote and accept it

Comment: Have your tried it? I tried as it was mentioned - `jmeter.hidpi.mode=true
jmeter.hidpi.scale.factor=2.0
jmeter.toolbar.icons.size=32x32
jmeter.tree.icons.size=24x24`. Restarted JMeter -> result is the same as it was before.

Comment: What is you OS ? and are you using 3.0 (just a confirmation) ?

Comment: I have Windows 8.1

Comment: Hi,Any feedback on answer ?

Comment: I set the Cross Platform view -> tried to set property even to `jmeter` file. Always, I use `jmeterw.cmd` on Windows for opening JMeter UI. But result is the same font is the same. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

JMeter 4.0 update :

Before any update of Jmeter setting

[image: Before any update of Jmeter setting]

After the update of Jmeter setting

[image]
JMeter 4.0 update using Windows 10 :

```
1. Go here : C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin 
2. Open to edit this : jmeter.properties 
3. Over here you need to update all required fields for you 

This is what I changed and it looks good to me :

jmeter.loggerpanel.display=true
jmeter.loggerpanel.enable_when_closed=true
jmeter.loggerpanel.maxlength=1000
jmeter.gui.refresh_period=500
jmeter.hidpi.mode=true
jmeter.hidpi.scale.factor=2.0
jmeter.toolbar.icons=org/apache/jmeter/images/toolbar/icons-toolbar.properties
jmeter.toolbar=new,open,close,save,save_as_testplan,|,cut,copy,paste,|,expand,collapse,toggle,|,test_start,test_stop,test_shutdown,|,test_start_remote_all,test_stop_remote_all,test_shutdown_remote_all,|,test_clear,test_clear_all,|,search,search_reset,|,function_helper,help
jmeter.toolbar.icons.size=48x48
jmeter.icons=org/apache/jmeter/images/icon_1.properties
jmeter.tree.icons.size=48x48
save_automatically_before_run=true


onload.expandtree=true
jsyntaxtextarea.wrapstyleword=true

jsyntaxtextarea.linewrap=true

jsyntaxtextarea.codefolding=true
jsyntaxtextarea.maxundos=50
jsyntaxtextarea.font.family=Hack

jsyntaxtextarea.font.size=28
loggerpanel.usejsyntaxtext=true
view.results.tree.max_size=10485760


please refer : https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html
```

Comment: May you show some image with how it was before properties update and after? It will help a lot of.

Comment: @nazar_art , once you download Jmeter you will see default settings and most of settings are commented out. And when you open to jmeter.bat or jmeter.jar you will see small icons all over on Jmeter UI. To fix that issue you just need to follow my instructions. I don't think you need images for that. Even after this you are facing some struggle than let me know.

Comment: When I wrote about some image, I meant about Jmeter UI screenshots. Snippets with `jmeter.properties` are obvious.

Comment: Nice solution, but the elements of the test tree have the text trimmed on top and at the bottom. The height of tree elements is not large enough. Any thoughts on how to get around this?

Comment: I have seen this type issue when I drag and drop Jmeter from my laptop to different resolution monitor. But I am good for with over all UI. I can tell you one trick-- can you please try to open/close multiple times ? pleas share pics of your issue  ..let me see what I can do.

Answer (score 2):

Using Jmeter 3.2

> Options > Zoom In

Zoomed some panes but not others. 
However modifying apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\jmeter.properties works. Tested with Win 10.

```
#jmeter.hidpi.mode=false
# To enable pseudo-hidpi mode change to true
jmeter.hidpi.mode=true
# HiDPI scale factor
#jmeter.hidpi.scale.factor=1.0
# Suggested value for HiDPI
jmeter.hidpi.scale.factor=2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

In `Jmeter 3.1` and `3.2`, uncomment below lines in `jmeter.properties` file, and restart the `Jmeter`. It worked and the font size increased for all the icons and components

**jmeter.hidpi.mode=true**

**jmeter.hidpi.scale.factor=2.0**

Comment: Thanks that was really useful since I get tired of Option -> Zoom in. I also prefer and set the jmeter.hidpi.scale.factor to 1.5 since 2.0 was a bit too much for me :)

Answer (score 1):

After setting the following properties in bin\jmeter.properties it looks better

```
jmeter.hidpi.mode=true
jmeter.hidpi.scale.factor=2.0
jmeter.toolbar.icons.size=32x32
jmeter.tree.icons.size=24x24
jsyntaxtextarea.font.family=Hack 
jsyntaxtextarea.font.size=28
```

ref: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html