# How to change JMeter http request font color

Tags: jmeter

I'm currently running latest JMeter 5.3 on Mac Catalina and noticed the text color of the sampler request body is hard to read (see attached screenshot). Is there a way to configure the text color?

Thanks

[image: JMeter UI Screenshot]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899553/how-to-change-font-size-for-jmeter this might help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the look and feel option available in Jmeter and check if the visibility is better.

Comment: Yeah, I guests that's probably the best option I've got, even though I wanted to keep the theme in general but only to change the text color originally.